# How to know if scipy function uses C code?

Tags: numpy, scipy

Does anyone knows whether scipy.signal.argrelmax and scipy.integrate.simps uses C code in in their sourcecodes or are they in pure python? I wan to speed up using Numba, so asking it.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html

Comment: I think most of scipy is actually wrapped *Fortran* libraries (not C).

Comment: `argrelmax` is defined in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.py; `simps` is defined in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py

Comment: There are actually links to the source code *in the links you've provided*.

Comment: Checking out the source codes, it became too difficult for me to figure out whether they use C or Fortran, any ideas please.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Checking out the source codes, it became too difficult for me to figure out whether they use C or Fortran, any ideas please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing through a couple of levels of calls, it looks like `argrelmax` ends up using this loop:

```
def _boolrelextrema(data, comparator...)
    # comparator - a function
    ....
    results = np.ones(data.shape, dtype=bool)
    main = data.take(locs, axis=axis, mode=mode)
    for shift in xrange(1, order + 1):
        plus = data.take(locs + shift, axis=axis, mode=mode)
        minus = data.take(locs - shift, axis=axis, mode=mode)
        results &= comparator(main, plus)
        results &= comparator(main, minus)
        if(~results.any()):
            return results

    order :  How many points on each side to use for the comparison
```

So if `order` isn't very large, the amount of iteration is small, and shouldn't affect the speed too much.

`simps` after setup uses

```
def _basic_simps(y,start,stop,x,dx,axis):
    nd = len(y.shape)
    if start is None:
        start = 0
    step = 2
    all = (slice(None),)*nd
    slice0 = tupleset(all, axis, slice(start, stop, step))
    slice1 = tupleset(all, axis, slice(start+1, stop+1, step))
    slice2 = tupleset(all, axis, slice(start+2, stop+2, step))

    if x is None:  # Even spaced Simpson's rule.
        result = add.reduce(dx/3.0 * (y[slice0]+4*y[slice1]+y[slice2]),
                                    axis)
    else:
        # Account for possibly different spacings.
        ...
    return result
```

By using `add.reduce` with a predefined set of slices, I'd guess it's as fast as you can get.

So these aren't specially coded in `C`, but they make efficient use of `numpy` vectorized operations.  My guess is that speeding them up with `numpy` and/or `cython` will take a lot of work - unless you focus a few special cases.